# Scroll not working when dragging tasks in DHTMLX gantt

Tags: javascript, jquery, dhtmlx, gantt-chart

I use order_branch config to drag and drop tasks (http://docs.dhtmlx.com/gantt/api__gantt_order_branch_config.html). It works OK but I found that I can't scroll the chart when I'm dragging. So I can't drag tasks out of visible area(top and bottom). How can I configure dhtmlxGantt to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can drag task and scroll the mouse wheel at the same time.